# Dont see function inside Promise

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var c = function(address, abiJson){
    var _ = this;
    this.data = {
            wallet: false,
            account:{
                address: false
            },
            contract:{
                address: address
            }
    };
    this.abi = $.getJSON(abiJson, function(abi){
        _.data.abi = abi;
        if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
            window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            window.cont = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
        }
    });
    this.getData = function(cb){
        if(typeof _.data.abi !== 'undefined'){
            _.updateData.done(() => {
                cb(_.data);
            });
        }
        else{
            _.abi.then(() => {_.updateData
            })
            .done(() => {
                cb(_.data);
            });
        }
    }
    this.updateData = Promise.all([
            _.get('x'),
            _.get('y')
        ])
        .then(values => { 
            _.data.x.y= values[0];
            _.data.x.z= values[1];
        })
        .then(() => {
            Promise.all([
                _.get('v', 1),
                _.get('v', 2),
            ])
            .then(values => {
                _.data.y = values;
            });
        });
    this.get = function(method, args){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            window.cont[method](args, function(error, result){
                if(!error) resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

When I get the function `_.get('x').then((x) => console.log (x))` outside the updateData function, I get all the data. But when I call the `getData` function I get errors for all the get functions `_.get is not a function`.

I just don't see where is my mistake. I'm new in js using Promise.

Comment: Problem on this line?: `            _.abi.then(() => {_.updateData
            })`

Comment: You are not explicitly returning the values in updateData to allow chaining of the promise. Make sure to add return statements when you intent to use then() down the line.

Comment: please can u rewrite code.

Comment: _.get is not a function - i see this error in console

Comment: When and how do you call `c`.  If you don't call it as a constructor or object method,, '_' is the global object. Not sure  what you mean by " call outside " - how can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: When i comment all UpdateData function and ABI function, then a call _.get('x').then((x) => console.log (x)) its work.

Comment: var dsg = new c('x', '/json/dsgABI.json');
 dsg.getData(function(e){
  console.log(e);
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cut-down version of the question:

```js
var C = function(address, abiJson){
    var _ = this;
    this.updateData = Promise.all([
            _.get('x'),
            _.get('y')
        ]);
    this.get = function( arg){ return Promise.resolve( arg)};
}
var c = new C();
c.updateData.then( values => console.log(values));
```

Calling `get` inside the array initializer argument of the `Promise.all` call errors because `get` has yet to be added as a method of `_` (which is set to `this`). Adding the `get` method before creating the array solves the immediate problem:

```js
var C = function(address, abiJson){
    var _ = this;
    // add get method first:
    this.get = function( arg){ return Promise.resolve( arg)};
    this.updateData = Promise.all([
            _.get('x'),
            _.get('y')
        ]);
}
var c = new C();
c.updateData.then( values => console.log(values));
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer with before and after examples

Comment: Yes, you are right. You showed me the right way. You are also right, thanks

Answer (score -1):

_ variable cannot be used that way. You can use it when you call it as a function, but cannot be used when you are creating an object. 
You can bind the scope using bind for the functions. For arrow functions, the scope will be retained. Try the following code. I just replaced _ with this for all the functions and binded this to the callback of getJSON. If you use arrow function there also, bind will not be necessary.

```
var c = function(address, abiJson){
    this.data = {
            wallet: false,
            account:{
                address: false
            },
            contract:{
                address: address
            }
    };
    this.abi = $.getJSON(abiJson, function(abi){
        this.data.abi = abi;
        if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
            window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            window.cont = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
        }
    }.bind(this));
    this.getData = function(cb){
        if(typeof this.data.abi !== 'undefined'){
            this.updateData.done(() => {
                cb(this.data);
            });
        }
        else{
            this.abi.then(() => {this.updateData
            })
            .done(() => {
                cb(this.data);
            });
        }
    }
    this.get = function(method, args){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            window.cont[method](args, function(error, result){
                if(!error) resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
    this.updateData = Promise.all([
            this.get('x'),
            this.get('y')
        ])
        .then(values => { 
            this.data.x.y= values[0];
            this.data.x.z= values[1];
        })
        .then(() => {
            Promise.all([
                this.get('v', 1),
                this.get('v', 2),
            ])
            .then(values => {
                this.data.y = values;
            });
        });

}
```

Comment: Updated the code. Put get function before updateData function.

Comment: `_` is a perfectly valid variable name. I believe the "lodash" library reserves it for library calls but that's not the case here.

Comment: I am not saying _ variable is invalid. I'm just saying variable cannot be used that way when you are instantiate object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Not at all. I had to rewrite the code a bit, as I found some errors. But you showed me the right way, thanks.